# Why is my karma test runs without angular application?

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, karma-runner

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w00Jw.png)

So i'm testing angular app with selenium, jasmine, karma. But things don't go well.
When i run it by "ng serve" - app works fine
But on "ng test" it only runs tests with empty screen. Why there's no app?

I updated my config file.

Comment: `ng e2e`
Builds and serves an Angular application, then runs end-to-end tests.

Comment: `ng test`
Runs unit tests in a project.

Comment: https://angular.io/cli

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-end-to-end-testing-with-angular-d175f751cb9c